# Why do I have an empty row at the end of my GridView?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have always an empty row in the end of my GridView

```
 gv_remboursement.DataSource = listResult;
 gv_remboursement.VirtualItemCount = iTotal;
 gv_remboursement.DataBind();
 listResultContent.Visible = isVisible;
```

`listResult` contains the list that I fill from the database.

Comment: Are you using paging? Have you inspected `listResult`, does it contain an empty item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm that headers/footers/pagers (if used) aren't affecting the count. Run the SQL separately to confirm dataset count.

Comment: thx in fact the showFooter in my HTML code was "true" so that was the problem